# making matplotlib stacked bar chart interactive in jupyter using plotly

Tags: matplotlib, plotly, jupyter, interactive

First time using jupyter & plotly, so I'm really struggling

This is my code

```
# import packages
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.gridspec as gridspec
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
import plotly.plotly as py
import plotly.tools as tls

from plotly.graph_objs import *
py.sign_in("x", "y")

tls.set_credentials_file(username='x', api_key='y')
tls.get_credentials_file()

fig1 = plt.figure()

%matplotlib notebook

# load data
revels_data = pd.read_csv("directory.data.txt")
rd = revels_data

# grouped bar plot
grouped = rd.groupby(["Packet number", "Flavour"])["Contents"].sum().unstack().fillna(0)
grouped.plot(kind="bar", stacked=True, color=["#a2653e", "#a6814c", "#fd5956", "#fd8d49", "#9c6da5", "#c9ae74"])

# title and axis labels
plt.title("NUMBER OF REVELS PER PACKET", weight="bold")
plt.ylabel("Contents")
plt.xlabel("Packet")

# plot median line
median = 19
plt.axhline(median, color='grey', linestyle='dashed', linewidth=0.5)

# legend properties
plt.legend(loc=2, prop={"size":7})

# extend y axis to fit legend in
axes = plt.gca()
axes.set_ylim([0,30])

# show plot
plt.show()
```

which produces the plot:

[image]

This displays in jupyter fine.

Now, what I want to do it add hover functionality essentially exactly like this example:

https://plot.ly/matplotlib/bar-charts/#stacked-bar-chart-with-labels

where hovering the mouse over each bar shows the flavour distribution per pack.

i.e: individual tabs for:
total: a,
orange: b,
toffee: c,
etc.
appear when hovering over each packet's bar in their respective flavour's colour.

I have had a fiddle for about 3 hours but I am getting no where.

Please help, thanks!

EDIT:

```
# import packages
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.gridspec as gridspec
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
import plotly.plotly as py
import plotly.tools as tls

from plotly.graph_objs import *
py.sign_in("x", "y")

tls.set_credentials_file(username='x', api_key='y')
tls.get_credentials_file()

%matplotlib notebook

# load data
revels_data = pd.read_csv(".txt")
rd = revels_data

fig1 = plt.figure()
ax = mpl_fig.add_subplot

# grouped bar plot
grouped = rd.groupby(["Packet number", "Flavour"])["Contents"].sum().unstack().fillna(0)
ax.grouped.plot(kind="bar", stacked=True, color=["#a2653e", "#a6814c", "#fd5956", "#fd8d49", "#9c6da5", "#c9ae74"])

# title and axis labels
plt.title("NUMBER OF REVELS PER PACKET", weight="bold")
plt.ylabel("Contents")
plt.xlabel("Packet")

# plot median line
median = 19
plt.axhline(median, color='grey', linestyle='dashed', linewidth=0.5)

# legend properties
plt.legend(loc=2, prop={"size":7})

# extend y axis to fit legend in
axes = plt.gca()
axes.set_ylim([0,30])

# show plot
plotly_fig = tls.mpl_to_plotly(fig1)
py.plot()
```

error: AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'grouped'

Comment: The code you show, is the code that works fine, it seems. However in order to help you one would need to know the code that you cannot get to work. So in principle the linked example shows you what to do; you'd therefore need to implement that and update your question. You then need to be very specific about what the result is and in how far it's not what you expect. If you get an error, report about the error trace.

Comment: my code is completely different though. the example given has manually inputed data, manually created plot etc. I want to essentially know if its possible to use all my existing design parameters WHILST making it interactive, essentially. The process is so much different to the example i posted, I just posted it as a visual representation of what it is I am trying to achieve.

Comment: Yes you can do it and the way it works is exactly like in the example you link to. At the moment one cannot answer this question as it would essentially only the example code copied. Again, if you have a problem implementing it, show a [mcve] of the code that causes the problem.

Comment: pls help me ernest

Comment: Please add some data to reproduce it, we don't have access to `"directory.data.txt"`

Comment: @MaximilianPeters I have edited the post with data

Comment: I'm happy to help, but I have given two comments on what I would need to have in order to be able to help you. If you can provide a clear problem description and the code that causes the problem, I can help you. Otherwise not.

Comment: ernest, i fundamentally do not know how to apply this process to my code. i have never used plotly before. if its as simple as you describe, it would be fantastic if you could help

Comment: Replace the barplot in the example code with your own barplot. That's it. If you have done that and it doesn't work, post your code together with a problem description into the question. (Mind that because you use some file we don't have access to, we cannot provide you with a runnable solution out of the box)

Comment: ok i have done that, but the issue was that it doesnt like the fact i have put ax. in front of grouped. hence why i was unsure how to implement this type of interactivity to MY graph as opposed to the example graph created completely for and in plotly. my post is updated with current code and error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you already have an axes, you can provide it to the pandas plot function of a dataframe `df` using the `ax` argument,

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
df.plot(... , ax=ax)
```

Try this code (no guarantee that it works, since I cannot text it):

```
# import packages
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
import plotly.offline as py
import plotly.tools as tls

from plotly.graph_objs import *
#py.sign_in("x", "y")

#tls.set_credentials_file(username='x', api_key='y')
#tls.get_credentials_file()

#%matplotlib notebook

# load data
flavours=["orange", "toffee", "chocolate", "malteser", "raisin", "coffee"]
num = np.arange(0, 6*36) % 36
flavs = np.random.choice(flavours, size=len(num))
conts = np.random.randint(0,6, len(num))

rd = pd.DataFrame({"Packet number":num ,"Flavour":flavs,"Contents" : conts})

fig1 = plt.figure(figsize=(10,8))
ax = fig1.add_subplot(111)

# grouped bar plot
grouped = rd.groupby(["Packet number", "Flavour"])["Contents"].sum().unstack().fillna(0)
grouped.plot(kind="bar", stacked=True, legend=False,
             color=["#a2653e", "#a6814c", "#fd5956", "#fd8d49", "#9c6da5", "#c9ae74"], ax=ax)

#ax.plot([1,3])

# title and axis labels
plt.title("NUMBER OF REVELS PER PACKET")
plt.ylabel("Contents")
plt.xlabel("Packet")

# plot median line, not shown in plotly
median = 19
ax.axhline(median, color='grey', linestyle='dashed', linewidth=0.5)


# show plot
plotly_fig = tls.mpl_to_plotly(fig1)

# For Legend
plotly_fig["layout"]["showlegend"] = True
# change this to label the legend
#plotly_fig["data"][0]["name"] = "Men"
#plotly_fig["data"][1]["name"] = "Women"


plot_url = py.plot(plotly_fig, filename='stacked-bar-chart.html')
```

[image]

Comment: TypeError: plot() missing 1 required positional argument: 'figure_or_data', what should i put inside py.plot() ?

Comment: both ax and plotly_fig give errors of TypeError: argument of type 'AxesSubplot' is not iterable and PlotlyEmptyDataError: Empty data list found. respectively

Comment: I updated the code. In order to test the code I needed to invent some dataframe. This is what should have been done by the one asking the question.

Comment: this is awesome ernest, thankyou. i have a query regarding the dataframe though. what changes do i make to use the actual data from csv file in the format shown in my original post as opposed to randomly generated values? thanks again

Comment: @importantofbeingernest last question: is there a way to make the plot fundamentally larger? its too squashed atm